# Passing multiple parameters to render function in order to knit an html?

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, knitr

I want to create a parametric Rmd document where the user will input in a list
these parameters below and run the render() function to knit the document.
This is my .Rmd file:

```
title: "DanceWize NSW report"
output: "html_pretty"
params:
    bump_in_date:"09-03-2018"
    bump_out_date:"10-03-2018"
    input_file:"ClientFiles/input_data.csv"
    operating_hours:"15:00-23:15"
    volunteers:"10"
    staff:"1 staff–DanceWize NSW Coordinator (Dan)"
```

This is my render function with the declaration of parameters (separate R script).

```
bump_in_date = "09-03-2018"
bump_out_date = "10-03-2018"
input_file = "ClientFiles/input_data.csv"
operating_hours = "15:00-23:15"
volunteers = "10"
staff = "1 staff–DanceWize NSW Coordinator (Dan)"

parameters = list(bump_in_date = bump_in_date,
              bump_out_date = bump_out_date,
              input_file = input_file,
              operating_hours = operating_hours,
              volunteers = volunteers,
              staff = staff
)

render("ReportInitial.Rmd", output_format = prettydoc::html_pretty(theme = "leonids"), output_file = "Report.html", encoding = "UTF-8", clean = TRUE, params = list())
```

If I send an empty list, the knitting succeeds, but if I put

```
params = parameters
```

in the render function, I receive the following error:

```
Error in knit_params_get(input_lines, params) :
  render params not declared in YAML: bump_in_date
Calls: render -> knit_params_get
```

I do define the parameters and I can confirm that parameters variable is a named list vector as it is expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simply to delete:

```
params:
      param1:
      etc.
```

in the header of the Rmd file. Furthermore, since the list I am passing to 
render() is parameters, you can access these variables as parameters$variable
in the Rnotebook and not as params$variable.